# Why is Filch's cat called "Mrs.Norris"?

Tags: harry-potter

This is an unusual name to give to a cat. The title "Mrs." is given to someone who is married. Does this mean that Mrs. Norris is married? If yes, where is her husband?

Or is Norris her first name? Then her full name would be Mrs. Norris Filch. But why would a man marry a cat in the first place?

Comment: There is a question titled 'Was Argus Filch's cat, Mrs Norris,  a transmorgrified human or an unregistered animagus ' ?  ; My question does not deal with the species status of  Mrs Norris but her naming scheme., which is not discussed in the quoted question.

Comment: Anecdotally, I know and have known a few people who named thier cats Mrs something, predating Harry Potter. So maybe it's just a thing people do

Comment: I think you're reading too much into it. People name animals weird things.

Comment: https://www.boredpanda.com/funny-pet-names/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=organic

Comment: Anyone can name a cat anything for any reason or no reason. In all likelihood, there *isn't* a reason why the cat is named Mrs. Norris.

Comment: Why don't you think her first name might be mrs?

Comment: @user13267 - Cats are often given honorifics that they don't deserve. David Baddiel's cat was famously named *Chairman Meow* and I don't believe that cat ever served as the chairman of anything.

Answer (score 12):

> **Lydon:** **What about names themselves? Muggles, to begin, but the whole catalogue of - er - wizards: Albus Dumbledore, Voldemort - er - Hagrid.**
>
> **JKR:** *I'm big on names - I like names, generally. You have to be really careful giving me your name if it's an unusual one, because you will turn up in book six. Erm - I - I collect - some of them are invented; Voldemort is an invented name, Malfoy is an invented name, Quidditch is invented, erm - but I also collect them, from all kinds of places: maps, street names, people I meet, old books, old saints, erm - **[Mrs Norris](https://janeausten.fandom.com/wiki/Mrs._Norris), people will have recognised, comes from Jane Austen.** Erm - Dumbledore is an old English word meaning bumblebee. Because Albus Dumbledore is very fond of music, I always imagined him as sort of humming to himself a lot.*
>
> <sub><sup>[J.K. Rowling interview transcript, The Connection (WBUR Radio), 12 October, 1999](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/1099-connectiontransc2.htm)</sup></sub>

It's plausible that in-universe Filch is also a fan of *Mansfield Park*, hence choosing the name.